How to avoid error 404 on refresh with angular app on IIS that contains special characters like "%2"
I have an Angular App (V17), hosted on IIS.
I have a route https://mysite/myapp/b%2fBP1SQsgyE%3D
I can reach it the first time but I can't refresh. The server respond with 404.
The issue comes from the special character %2f that is interpreted as a /, so instead of reaching "myapp" with the encrypted param, it tries to go to "myapp/b/2Bp......".
How can I have an URL with encoded characters so ?
I already have the redirection web.config, so I can refresh if there is no encoded character like "%2".
I don't want to use param with "?param=". I want to keep route logic.

if not using hash location strategy seems like you should redirect everything but endpoint URLs to index.html.  Show your redirection code.

Encoded URLs are often problematic, so you should revise your design to get rid of them if possible. When not possible, utilize IIS logs or failed request tracing to see which request filtering rules caused the 404 errors and you might disable them for this web app.

I think I will change the encryption and remove characters which are encoded in the url.
Thx for your comments.

By default Angular application don't use a hash prefix on URL. The reason of the error 404 on refresh is that the web server receiving the request looks for a resource matching the full URL on the server, which doesn't exist because the angular portion of the RUL refers to a route in your angular app.
Try to use URL Rewrite Rule to prevent 404 error after page refresh.
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>


I already have this web.config and this is working for Url without special characters.

Try to add another rewrite rule before the above to detect and replace the %2f before it reaches the server.  Or as the @browsermator  saying, enable  the  useHash  to ture.
